# How do I fix corrupt files with 'sfc /scannow' in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, file-corruption, wfp

I saw this question [How do I repair the corrupted files found by sfc /scannow? "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them."](https://superuser.com/questions/694349/how-do-i-repair-the-corrupted-files-found-by-sfc-scannow-windows-resource-pro), but it was for Windows 7. Running the `sfc /scannow` command on my installation of Windows 8.1 gave me this error:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
>   of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
>   example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
>   supported in offline servicing scenarios.

I ran `chkdsk` and it found no problems.

Here is the complete log: http://sdrv.ms/1cOx19p

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.16384

Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.16384

Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was repaired.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: If the command was unable to help you have serious problems. We need the contents of CBS.log.  Also posts the results of `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Comment: Here is the CBS.log. http://sdrv.ms/1cOx19p. I ran the two dism commands also (see above).

Comment: Ahh, now `sfc` worked and did not find any problems!

Comment: I assume your problems are solved?  I won't post an answer because both commands already exist in past questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why DISM can fix it, because Microsoft still doesn't provide the RTM files to download:

```
2014-01-03 20:45:31, Info                  CSI    00000800 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-01-03 20:45:31, Info                  CSI    00000802 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-01-03 20:45:31, Info                  CSI    00000803 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:186{93}]"Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_prncacla"
```

You need to point to the WIM file of the Windows 8.1 RTM DVD to get the correct files:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

(where D: is your Windows DVD drive or mounted Win8.1 ISO

Comment: Not sure what a WIM, or RTM is. I don't have an 8.1 DVD. It came pre-installed with 8 and it updated itself with 8.1 through Windows Update.

Comment: @Chloe - `WIM` I believe stands for `Windows Image Manifest` its used to configure multiple machines.  But I don't see any evidence that DISM wasn't able to solve your the problem.

Comment: WIM is the format that Windows uses since Vista for the installation data. The user "moconnell1" (http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx#pi47623=12) had the same issue with WIn8, so looks like MS still doesn't provide the data for 8.1.