# How to Repair Corrupt System Files from a Installation Disc

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64, build 6.3.9600.16384,
using the Command Prompt with administrator privileges.

`sfc /scannow`

returns:

```
...found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
```

and

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

returns:

```
Error: 0x800f0906
The source files could not be downloaded.
```

(and the Windows Update Service is not able to start because those files are missing.)

also tried

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:wim:F:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess`

and returned:

```
Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Error: 0x800f081f
The source files could not be found.
```

I mounted the image, and tried from there.

`dism /mount-image /imagefile:F:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /mountdir:C:\offline`

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restoreHealth /source:c:\offline /limitaccess`

also returning:

```
Error: 0x800f081f
```

***How do I repair the Corrupt System Files?***

***Can I tell DISM to use the Windows installation disc as the source?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix corrupt files with 'sfc /scannow' in Windows 8.1?](http://superuser.com/questions/696783/how-do-i-fix-corrupt-files-with-sfc-scannow-in-windows-8-1)

Comment: @and31415, the poster on that question revolved his problem, but that answer did not solve mine.

Comment: Then you could copy the `CSB.log` file (which can usually found `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS`) to the desktop, compress it in a .zip/.7z archive, and upload it somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about). Then post the resulting link here for further inspection.

Comment: Here you go. This is `CSB.log` created by `sfc /scannow` [CSB.log](http://ge.tt/2ox3yVK1/v/0?c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Filtering the details

Running the `sfc /scannow` will produce a `CBS.log` report file (usually found in `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS`) which contains a wealth of information. In order to get the juicy bits, open a command prompt, and execute this command:

```
findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\sfc.txt"
```

The above command will:

1. Get all lines in the original file containing `[SR]`, which are the ones that track the repair attempts.
2. Remove all lines containing `verify` from what we got in the previous step in order to further reduce the clutter.
3. Write the results in the `sfc.txt` file for later analysis.

In this case, this would be the resulting file:

```
2014-02-19 17:08:47, Info                  CSI    0000008b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:49, Info                  CSI    0000008c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:49, Info                  CSI    0000008d [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:08:51, Info                  CSI    00000091 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:53, Info                  CSI    00000092 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:53, Info                  CSI    00000093 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:08:56, Info                  CSI    00000097 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-MediaViewerDistributed-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:57, Info                  CSI    00000098 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-MediaViewerDistributed-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:08:57, Info                  CSI    00000099 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000975 [SR] Repairing 3 components
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000977 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000978 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000979 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-MediaViewerDistributed-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097b [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097d [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-MediaViewerDistributed-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097f [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000980 [SR] Repair complete
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000981 [SR] Committing transaction
```

## Identifying the issues

Checking the file you can see the System File Checker tried to repair 3 components, but failed:

```
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000975 [SR] Repairing 3 components
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000977 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000978 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    00000979 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Generic.xbf" of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-MediaViewerDistributed-MediaShared, Version = 6.3.9600.16485, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
```

Each entry follows this rough scheme:

- `Cannot repair member file [...]"Generic.xbf"`
  The file that needs to be repaired.
- `of Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main,`
  The name of the package which the file belongs to.
- `Version = 6.3.9600.16485,`
  File version (major, minor, build and revision).
- `pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9),`
  The targeted [processor architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- `Culture neutral, [...],`
  Either neutral or the related [culture name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) if localized.
- `file is missing`
  Reason the file need to be repaired.

There are three `Generic.xbf` files which are missing. Additionally, all of them share this bit of information:

```
2014-02-19 17:23:00, Info                  CSI    0000097b [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB2914218~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.3.2914218-1_neutral_GDR"
```

This means the file are included in the KB2914218 Windows update.

## Manual repair

1. Get the [KB2914218](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41573) update package.
2. Extract the downloaded `.msu` file using [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) in a folder named after the original file (e.g. `Windows8.1-KB2914218-x64`).
3. Open a command prompt as administrator, and navigate to the actual folder by using the following command:

   ```
   cd /d "X:\Whatever\Windows8.1-KB2914218-x64"
   ```
4. Expand the cabinet archive containing the update files in the current directory:

   ```
   expand Windows8.1-KB2914218-x64.cab -f:* %cd%
   ```
5. Each package has an associated `.manifest` file which lists the bundled files. In order to determine where each file is stored, run the following command by replacing `packagaName` and `fileName.ext` with the actual values:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %A in ('"findstr /i /m /c:"packageName" *.manifest"') do @for /f "delims=" %B in ('"findstr /i /m /c:"fileName.ext" %A"') do @echo %~nB;fileName.ext>>fixes.txt
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %A in ('"findstr /i /m /c:"Microsoft-Windows-Camera-LockScreenCamera-Main" *.manifest"') do @for /f "delims=" %B in ('"findstr /i /m /c:"Generic.xbf" %A"') do @echo %~nB;Generic.xbf>>fixes.txt
   ```
6. Repeat step 5 for any other file that needs to be fixed.
7. Take ownership and full control over the `C:\Windows\winsxs` folder:

   ```
   takeown /f "%windir%\winsxs" /a
   icacls "%windir%\winsxs" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:(OI)(CI)(F) /q
   ```
8. Create any missing folder:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %G in (fixes.txt) do @if not exist "%windir%\winsxs\%~G\" @md "%windir%\winsxs\%~G"
   ```
9. Take full control of the required folders:

   ```
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %G in (fixes.txt) do takeown /f "%windir%\winsxs\%~G" /a >nul & icacls "%windir%\winsxs\%~G" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:(OI)(CI)(F) /q
   ```
10. Restore the files:

    ```
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %A in (fixes.txt) do copy /y ".\%A\%B" "%windir%\winsxs\%A\%B"
    ```
11. Repeat the system file check-up to ensure the issues were fixed:

    ```
    sfc /scannow
    ```

## References

- [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us)
- [How to Run "SFC /SCANNOW" Command at Boot or in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Thank you. `SFC /SCANNOW` didn't fint any problems after that.

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Why don't you write a tutorial in eightforums.com or similar?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows can't boot, you can run SFC from Windows recovery console:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\ /offwindir=d:\windows
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/03/windows-reparar-archivos-del-sistema.html