# Extracting a file from the WinSxS folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, winsxs

Specifically, I'd like to get the file `explorer.exe` of version `6.3.9600.17238` (from Windows 8.1 Update 1). I have the following file on my system:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-explorer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17238_none_4d01a98581e82d4f\explorer.exe
```

But it looks like some kind of diff, it's only 216 KB, while the original file is around 2 MB.

How can I extract the file? Or alternatively, is there another location where I can find this file, locally or online?

I need the file of this specific version for a tool I'm developing. Not in order to repair an OS installation.

Comment: What version of IE are you trying to fix exactly?  What version of Windows are you using?  If you are using Windows 8 this is extremely easy to fix.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not IE (`iexplore.exe`), it's the File Explorer. I don't try to fix anything, I need that specific version for some tool I'm developing. I tried to find it online, but no luck. All I found were the file hashes, but that doesn't really help.

Comment: Of course, you are right.  Answer the rest of my question(s).

Comment: @Ramhound It's from Windows 8.1 Update 1, which can be deduced from the file version (`6.3.9600` with QFE larger than `17000`).

Comment: I shouldn't have to deduce anything.  Update your question to reflect what operating system your using.  Are you trying to extract the file so you can repair the installation or do something else entirely?

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question.

Comment: So [this](http://superuser.com/questions/718805/how-to-repair-corrupt-system-files-from-a-installation-disc) questions explains how to extract a file from a install.wim image.

Comment: Use this tool https://github.com/hfiref0x/SXSEXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Explorer.exe` in version `6.3.9600.17238` is part of the [August 2014 Update Rollup for Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2975719).

You can use the Windows inbox tool `expand.exe` to expand the MSU and next the CAB file to extract the `Explorer.exe`:

```
expand -F:* Windows8.1-KB2975719-x64.msu C:<target_dir>
cd <target_dir>
expand -F:* Windows8.1-KB2975719-x64.cab C:<target_dir>
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed! A couple of questions: 1. How did you find out that the file resides in this particular update package? 2. Is there a list of all `explorer.exe` versions? I'd like to know which versions between build `17039` and `17238` exist.

Comment: I used regedit.exe, opened this key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\wow64_microsoft-windows-explorer_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_dc01e295aea4de26** and here I can see that this version belongs to this KB article. I don't know such a list.