# Windows 8.1 Corrupt System Files Causes Computer to Freeze and Reappear after "Fixing"

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, file-corruption

My computer freezes randomly from time to time and will not respond again until I completely power off the system.  I am running Windows 8.1 x64 (dual booted with Linux if that's important).  Below is the resulting of running `sfc /scannow` and `findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify"` (this was suggested on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/718805/how-to-repair-corrupt-system-files-from-a-installation-disc)).  I have tried `DISM.exe`, `SFCFix.exe`, and the steps listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/718805/how-to-repair-corrupt-system-files-from-a-installation-disc).  None of these have been able to fix the corrupt files, although all report back that the problem has been successfully resolved.  The exception is the post I referenced above, which did not even create the fixes.txt file created in step 5 of Manual repair.  I have run chkdsk and I did not notice any errors, so I do not believe the problem is caused by the hard drive.  I am getting a little tired of this computer freezing and losing work, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
2015-06-26 09:04:21, Info                  CSI    000004b0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:04:21, Info                  CSI    000004b2 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:04:23, Info                  CSI    000004b4 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:04:23, Info                  CSI    000004b5 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.3068708-1_neutral_GDR"
2015-06-26 09:04:23, Info                  CSI    000004b7 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:04:23, Info                  CSI    000004b8 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.3068708-1_neutral_GDR"
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008de [SR] Repairing 1 components
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e1 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e5 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e6 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.3068708-1_neutral_GDR"
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e8 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.3.9600.17842, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008e9 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:154{77}]"Package_1_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.3068708-1_neutral_GDR"
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008eb [SR] Repair complete
2015-06-26 09:09:17, Info                  CSI    000008ec [SR] Committing transaction
```

Comment: DISM is suppose to determine if your WinSxS folder is corrupt, while SFC will actually fix your system files by using the contents of the WinSxS, these errors indicate you do infact have system file corruption ( obviously ).  Have you tryed downloading a Windows 8.1 and using its WinSxS folder to repair the WinSxS on your drive.  In my experience a healthy drive, one in which should not be replaced, does not generate these types of errors.

Comment: I thought that was basically what the post of linked to was trying to accomplish.  I do have an installation disk though.  Should I just copy and paste all the files in the Sources\sxs folder to the WinSxS folder? These folders seem similar, but do not have all the same files/folders.

Comment: Just copy and paste, no, do what I suggested.  You have to manually indicate to both SFC and DISM you want ot use another source directory.  Look up the syntax if you don't know it.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not clear to me.  The problem appears to persist even after doing this.  I executed `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E:\Sources\sxs /LimitAccess` which displayed the message `The restore operation completed successfully.  The component store corruption was repaired.`, but `sfc /scannow` found corrupt files it was unable to fix.  The same files appear to be corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a expected output. Microsoft wrote this in the following KB article:

**Update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry** 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068708

> This update contains the following two manifests that are occasionally
>   updated by the Diagnostic Tracking Service:
>
> ```
> telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json
> utc.app.json
> ```
>
> The two files are marked as static files in the update. **When an**
>   **advanced user runs the System File Checker Tool (sfc.exe), the files**
>   **are unintentionally flagged as corrupted. There is no impact or actual**
>   **corruption on a device** that is running this update, and this issue
>   will be fixed in a later service update.

So ignore the issue until Microsoft fixed it with a new update.

Comment: Then what would be causing the system to randomly freeze?

Comment: something else. Press the CAPS LOCK key during the freeze and look if the light on the keyboard toggles or not.

Comment: I have before, nothing happens.  All lights (and sounds) that were on when the computer freezes stay on until powered off.

Comment: in this case you have a hardware issue. Test RAM with memtest86+ and CPU with Prime95.

Comment: Unfortunately, memtest86+ is not supported on UEFI systems (mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/258991/where-is-the-memtest-option-on-the-12-04-64-bit-live-cd)).  I did run the memory tester installed with Windows (described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer)) using the extended option, which did not detect any errors.  Should I try memtest86, which does work with UEFI?  Prime95 has been running for 14+ hrs now and has not detected any issues.  I also ran chkdsk and verified the hd using Linux, but neither found problems.