# Windows corrupted

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore

I execute `sfc /scannow` it tells me windows :

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
>   some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>   windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

I just want to know do i have to repair trough this solution or is there other ways?

[How do I repair the corrupted files found by sfc /scannow? "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them."](https://superuser.com/questions/694349/how-do-i-repair-the-corrupted-files-found-by-sfc-scannow-windows-resource-pro)

Note: please read this log. because of characters limitation i have post log here 
http://pastebin.com/5hH6YHWY

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I repair the corrupted files found by sfc /scannow? "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them."](http://superuser.com/questions/694349/how-do-i-repair-the-corrupted-files-found-by-sfc-scannow-windows-resource-pro)

Answer (score 1):

You have the well known `CNBJ2530.DPB` error. To fix it run the [new DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx)

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

I reported this error some time to Microsoft but Microsoft was never able to find the cause, even if they saw it internally on several systems.

Comment: Does it work on Windows 10 too?

Comment: @MerajalMaksud yes, the command works in Win8/8.1 and Windows 10